# Is Arquillian undeploy testing package too early?

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I have rest testing with Arquillian, however it just gives me 404s when I am trying to get there. What I found in logs:

```
3:04:30,320 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /d98c2952-075b-42ac-bf5b-e56940574105
23:04:30,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS018559: Deployed "d98c2952-075b-42ac-bf5b-e56940574105.war" (runtime-name : "d98c2952-075b-42ac-bf5b-e56940574105.war")
23:04:32,412 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017535: Unregistered web context: /d98c2952-075b-42ac-bf5b-e56940574105
23:04:32,418 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment d98c2952-075b-42ac-bf5b-e56940574105.war
23:04:32,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment d98c2952-075b-42ac-bf5b-e56940574105.war (runtime-name: d98c2952-075b-42ac-bf5b-e56940574105.war) in 46ms
23:04:32,472 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS014901: Content removed from location /home/dawid/java/tools/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/data/content/33/6bed642862d3cdee740b4f24aa8a9226a50bfc/content
23:04:32,472 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS018558: Undeployed "d98c2952-075b-42ac-bf5b-e56940574105.war" (runtime-name: "d98c2952-075b-42ac-bf5b-e56940574105.war")
Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 16.128 sec <<< FAILURE!
testGettingValues(com.sargent.rest.UserFileRestfulTest)  Time elapsed: 0.483 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
```

I can tell from logs that app is undeployed before its tested. Any ideas why?

Comment: Some more info and more of the logs would be helpful. Are you running your test as a client? Did the deployment fail?

Answer (score 0):

It probably wasn't un-deployed before the test failures. Arquillian will often output all of the server output before outputting any of the logs from JUnit. This has confused people on my team several times.

I would configure deploymentExportPath in your arquillian.xml file so you can get a saved copy of the war. You can then manually deploy it to the server and test for yourself if it is getting a 404. Only after that would I suspect that Arquillian is loading it incorrectly.